# Replace multiple symbols in a string differently in r

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I tried to recode values such as `(5,10]`,`(20,20]` to `5-10%`,`20-20%` using gsub. So, the first parenthesis should be gone, the comma should be changed to dash and the last bracket should be %. What I can do was only

```
x<-c("(5,10]","(20,20]")
gsub("\\,","-",x)
```

Then the comma is changed to the dash. How can I change others as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another alternative:

```
> gsub("\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\]", "\\1-\\2%", x)
[1] "5-10%"  "20-20%"
```

Comment: I like this one line solution. Thanks much.

Answer (score 4):

Keeping it very simple, a set of gsubs.

```
x <- c("(5,10]","(20,20]")
x <- gsub(",", "-", x) # remove comma
x <- gsub("\\(", "", x) # remove bracket
x <- gsub("]", "%", x) # replace ] by %
x
 "5-10%"  "20-20%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solution.

Using `regmatches` we extract all the numbers. We then combine every first and second number.

```
nrs <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", x))
nrs <- as.numeric(unlist(nrs))
i <- 1:length(nrs); i <- i[(i%%2)==1]
for(h in i){print(paste0(nrs[h],'-',nrs[h+1],'%'))}

[1] "5-10%"
[1] "20-20%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, an ugly one-liner:

```
sapply(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+", x)), function(x) paste0(x[1], "-", x[2], "%"))

[1] "5-10%"  "20-20%"
```